# Posting audio files as status update to Facebook from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, facebook, audio

I know this is a broad question, but I'm just wondering what the general approach would be.

I have an iPhone app that generates a WAV file. What would be the best way to allow the user to post it to his Facebook wall.

I would imagine this would involve holding the data on a server. Maybe a SoundCloud solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Soundcloud is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes , you are right - you should have a internal server in which you can post your audio file to server & get a return string of path that contains the media file - just post that link to Facebook using Graphh API Links , then if a user clicks that link which is media file url like http://yourserver.com/myaudio.mp3 - fb will play that media files.

For example - try Cinch iPhone App.